# How to map a key sequence to an IdeaVim key mapping

Tags: android-studio, vim, intellij-idea, ideavim

Currently, I'm attempting to organize some keyboard shortcuts for IdeaVim v0.48. I've run into a problem when I try to map shortcut "leader + ev" to an Intellij IDE action "ExtractVariable."

There is no official IDE action listed for extracting a variable, strangely enough, so I'm trying to map it to a function key.  Here's what I put into my .ideavimrc:

```
set <F15> = ^[,
map <F15> <leader>ev
```

where my IDE shortcut for extracting a variable is "Ctrl + Alt + ,"

I've followed multiple guides on this, and still don't understand how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question for others as the IJ Idea documentation is a little unclear:

The IDE action for "Extract Variable" is actually called "IntroduceVariable" if you want to call it from command mode (all other variable extraction actions begin with "Introduce" also). So to map this to a shortcut in IdeaVim, simply put this in your .ideavimrc:

```
map <what you want to use> :action IntroduceVariable<CR>
```